# Removing Small Elements from Array

Tags: python

just wondering why this little function to cut off small numbers from an array isn't working.

```
def chopper(values):
    for i in range(len(values)):
        if np.abs(values[i])<10**(-9):
            values=np.delete(values,i)
    return values

print(chopper(np.array([1,2,10**(-10),-10**(-10),3])))
```

I expect to get [1,2,3]. Instead I get an error message:
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you have deleted a value from the array, so your loop that loops over the length of the array now loops off the end of it.

Comment: also, keep in mind that after deletion, the indexes will change. 
Have a read here: https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/intro-to-python-for-data-science/chapter-2-python-lists?ex=15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing elements from the array with `np.delete` while iterating on the array (i continues to increase).

So you should either decrease the value of `i` everytime you delete a value like this:

```
import numpy as np

def chopper(values):
    i = 0
    continue_ = i < len(values)
    while continue_:
        if np.abs(values[i]) < 10**(-9):
            values=np.delete(values,i)
        else:
            i += 1
        continue_ = i < len(values)
    return values

print(chopper(np.array([1,2,10**(-10),-10**(-10),3])))
```

or embrace the power of numpy masks, that is much more efficient:

```
import numpy as np

def chopper(values):
    mask = np.abs(values) > 10**(-9)
    return values[mask]

print(chopper(np.array([1,2,10**(-10),-10**(-10),3])))
```

Of course this can be done in a one liner:

```
values = values[np.abs(values) > 10**(-9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you decrease the size of the array/list each time you delete an element.

You can use indexing if it is an numpy array :

```
values = values[np.abs(values) < 1e-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting a value from the `values` array while iterating through it.
If you remove an entry from the array, `len(values)` will send you out of the bounds of this array.

Fortunately, if you only want to filter an array, you can do that through a list comprehension in python

```py
def chopper(values):
    return [v for v in values if np.abs(v) >= 10**(-9)]
```

This will create a new array with only the selected elements